# Navigate from one Intent to another Intent in Alexa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am using ralyxa to work with Alexa. I have an audio, and have something else to do when this audio finishes.

As usual, the alexa triggers `PlaybackFinished` Intent. But this intent does not include any standard properties such as `outputSpeech`, `card`, or `reprompt` (This is what documentation says). I cannot trigger an output speech.

Is there any way to trigger a custom Intent, something like the following, which calls `CustomIntent` inside `PlaybackFinished` Intent?

```
intent 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished' do
  speech = PODCAST_REPEAT_OPTION
  CustomIntent
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished` request **you cannot** send a response with

1. `outputSpeech` or `reprompt`
2. Any other `AudioPlayer` directives
3. Any other directives from other interfaces.

Your skill can **only respond with** a `Stop` or `ClearQueue` directive to stop or clear the current audio playback queue.

However, before you get a `AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished`, you will receive a `AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished` to which you can send a `Play` directive (or  any `AudioPlayer` directive.) to continue streaming audio.

Standard response properties such as `outputSpeech`, `card`, and `reprompt` with `AudioPlayer` directives are possible when responding to a `LaunchRequest` or `IntentRequest`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, But is there a way I can keep the session in play without ending it, while playing Audio.Like, after the audio completes I want to play a text "Would you like to go to main menu?"

Comment: As of now it's not possible. Because the Alexa ends the  session as soon as it start playing an audio stream.

Comment: Once audio starts playing, user can only invoke any of the  playback control intents. Upon which which Alexa starts the session(it remember the last skill used) again and sends the request to your backend. For playback control intents,  invocation name is not required.